# How to send Mono of ResponseEntity of a class which has Flux/Mono attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am creating API with `Spring webflux` to measure the response time as compare to `Spring MVC` which has same code.

In `Spring MVC`, I send response with `ResponseEntity<HttpResponse>` .

```
public class HttpResponse {
    private Date timestamp = new Date();
    private int status;
    private boolean error;
    private String message;
    private Object data;

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return error;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public HttpResponse() {
        super();
    }
    public HttpResponse(int status, boolean error, String message, Object data) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.error = error;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And this is my return statement in requestMapping method:

```
return new ResponseEntity<HttpResponse>(new HttpResponse(httpStatus.value(), error, message, responseObject), httpStatus);
```

> httpStatus is instance of HttpStatus
>
> error is a boolean
>
> message is a String
>
> responseObject is a Object

This works fine, I get proper response.

In `Spring webflux`, I have used `Mono<ResponseEntity<HttpResponse>>` instead of `ResponseEntity<HttpResponse>` 
and this is the return statement in requestMapping method.

```
return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<HttpResponse>(new HttpResponse(httpStatus.value(), error, message, responseObj), httpStatus));
```

this gives this response

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-06-25T16:18:09.949+0000",
    "status": 200,
    "error": false,
    "message": "23",
    "data": {
        "scanAvailable": true
    }
}
```

I have passed a **Mono in  responseObj**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring WebFlux will only resolve top level Publishers - it is up to you to create such a pipeline.

In your case, you should have something like:

```
Mono<User> user = …
Mono<ResponseEntity> response = user.map(u -> new ResponseEntity(new HttpResponse(…, u));
return response;
```

Comment: No, it’s a reactor operator and very few do block. On the top of my head: block() does (a pretty clear name in this case)